# How to delete rows with particular values from datafreim?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delete-row

I have 2000 strings in 670 000 dataset I would like to drop. They are not full duplicates (this is why I couldn't use df.drop_duplicates()), but they have the same id, this is why I want to delete them.

I've tried this code and it works:

```
#found rows I want to delete:

user_id_list = df_users['user_uid'] 
counts = user_id_list.value_counts()
res = counts[counts > 1].index
res

for i in res:
    df_users = df_users.drop(df_users[(df_users["user_uid"] == i)].index)
```

but it takes about 10 minutes to operate. How I cam make it faster?

Comment: Very interesting question. my thought. Locate unique Indices, then subset your data using those unique indices.

Comment: use `drop_duplicates` with `subset` argument `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_uid'],keep='first')`

Comment: @Manakin, thank you! it works now.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep only one id, (so all IDs are unique), you have to decide which occurrence you want to keep, there are 2 options for you, `keep="last"` for keeping only last occurred ID in data frame. and `keep="first"` keep only first occurred ID.

```python
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset="ID", keep="first") # or keep="last"
```

if you want to remove all IDs that are occurred twice or more you should do `keep=False`